# how to use double quotes in document.write

Tags: vbscript

I am new to web programming,learning VBScript.I want to display few text boxes in a form using HTML tags.But when creating text box using this statement - document.write("input type="text"") something is going wrong and nothing is displayed in web page.I know I can create the text box using HTML outside of script block,but can we do it in document.write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
<script language=vbscript>
document.write("input type='text'") '=> input type="text"
document.write("input type=""text""") '=> input type="text"

'as suggested in other answer won't work 
'document.write("input type=\"text\"")
'document.write("input type='text'")
</script>
```

Comment: just a correction,when I used this code directly in my machine,it didn't work,since input is an HTML tag I put <> around.Then it is working now,thank you.

Answer (score 0):

either try 1 of the 2 following options:

1. document.write("input type=\"text\"")
2. document.write("input type='text'")

You are passing your doc.write function its parameter using double quotes, therefore you either have to escape them if you use double quotes again, or use single quotes around 'text'

Comment: dit you test your solution ? Gives nothing in both cases

Comment: Asker marked this with a VBScript tag. You can't escape double quotes with a backslash in VBScript, so your answer is not correct. Double quotes _can_ be escaped with another set of bunny ears like: `document.write("input type=""text""")`

Answer (score 0):

Always, use two quotation marks ("") within a string to represent a single quotation mark.

Example String - "Alex : "how are you", he said"

Wscript.Echo "Alex : ""how are you"", he said" 'Using double quotes

Same is the case when you try to insert html tags in a wbscript. Hope this helps.